# VALOR DE VARIABLE FPDF

Tags: php, bucle-for, condiciones, while, fpdf

Buen dia, resulta que tengo un inconveniente con la creacion de un PDF (Agrupado), extraida desde una base de datos, resulta que la variable $total se inicializa con un valor a cero, pero el primer registro del while, trae data como nombre, producto y total, que en este caso por ejemplo en la base de datos esta este registro

Banco:Universal

| Nombre | Producto | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Daniel | Agricola | $20 |
| Jaime | Individual | $50 |

Banco:Clarin

| Nombre | Producto | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cecilia | Agricola | $70 |
| David | Individual | $30 |

Al recorrer el while con FPDF me da

Banco:Universal

| Nombre | Producto | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Daniel | Agricola | $0 |
| Jaime | Individual |  |

Banco:Clarin
$50
Nombre Producto Total
Cecilia Agricola   $70
David  Individual
.
.
.

Banco:N
$30
Nombre Producto Total
Maria Agricola   $70
Jose  Individual

Alguien podria ayudarme, he intentado usar otras estructuras de control como do while, pero el valor de inicializacion me salta al segundo registro el valor total que le corresponderia, es decir esa condicion me genera que el while recorra el primer registro con cero pero el valor de total lo coloca en el segundo registro no en el primero, ayuda por favor.

Comment: Por favor, include el codigo PHP

Comment: while($row = sybase_fetch_array($respuesta)) 
{
    //AGRUPACION POR ASESOR
    $breakAsesor = $row['fu_funcionario'] != $lastAsesor;
    if ($breakAsesor) 
    {
      $pdf->SetX(10);
      report_product_totales($pdf, $productTotales);
      $pdf->SetX(127);
      report_saldos_totales2($pdf, $saldosTotales2);
      $pdf->SetX(152);
      report_riesgos_totales($pdf, $riesgosTotales);
      $pdf->SetX(170);
      report_socios_totales($pdf, $sociosTotales);
      $pdf->SetX(190);

Comment: report_valores_totales($pdf, $valoresTotales);
      if($maximo>0){
      $pdf->SetX(240);
      report_dias_maximo($pdf, $maximo);
      }
      $pdf->SetX(218);
      report_dias_minimo($pdf, $fechaMinima);
      $pdf->SetX(48);
      report_banco_total($pdf, $bancoTotal);
      $pdf->SetX(70);
      report_cliente_total($pdf, $clienteTotal);

Comment: $pdf->Ln();
      $pdf->Ln();
      $pdf->SetX(10);
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
      $pdf->Cell(20, -6, $row['fu_funcionario'] . ' - ' . $row['fu_nombre']);
      $productTotales =0;
      $saldosTotales2 =0;
      $riesgosTotales=0;
      $sociosTotales=0;
      $valoresTotales=0;
      $maximo=0;
      $fechaMinima= null;
      $bancoTotal=0;
      $clienteTotal=0;
    }

Comment: ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //AGRUPACION POR GRUPO
     $breakGrupo = $row['gr_grupo'] != $lastGrupo;
    if ($breakGrupo) 
    {
      $pdf->SetX(15);
      report_saldo($pdf,$saldoTotal);
      
      if($riesgoTotal>0){
        $pdf->SetX(13);
        report_riesgo($pdf,$riesgoTotal);
      }
      if($valorTotal>0){
        $pdf->SetX(20);
        report_valor($pdf,$valorTotal);
        $pdf->SetX(20);
        report_socios($pdf,$sociosTotal);
      }

Comment: Edita tu respuesta, no en los comentarios

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.